# can't phrase the rest request correctly with the right pagetoken query param

Tags: python, google-places-api

I place the following rest request:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?fields=types%2Cphotos%2Cformatted_address%2Cname%2Cpermanently_closed%2Copening_hours%2Crating%2Cuser_ratings_total%2Cplus_code&pagetoken=CrQCJAEAAGy5SDC_hwcBg_plNe50Q_tMu1aCllTBrRIJy9m2DkxFVGXNLDD3bz23kG7q1dlFSdlFgaKowMPyLP7ecoL3-qaATut7dw4ebP_zz1cVQh0uCZI4DxiQablPO2HVTe8AApfOtx258YyoV6N1liqxcrgv60YaEYCXVaOrG7uO0hh2ew1_831QWsondLKQLAH87GnqFIx456Z6-rXObuDCSpAK50LLFHroCJvWCyHg7uPnOK0QlWl0hEOwFCuGUSFIjAgrpr8XDcRSxwOkm_hr908I9JH9DWXGMCOc5v67OlVKAcHDumVifD9mUFYQrt6wWoaObUqnMcndN5nf_9gAmr3iVoiGxJPLWK2Ehb2SNqpIFqZCym1exBCpTrrySfYx_WBKwT68HbSAbI9052fiPpQSEGbnTS49qkXz3_Xn0eT0GoUaFEQ0qpquGT1LktIwybA4nXqOnw2P&location=13.026232%2C77.502529&key=MYKEY&input=car+service&inputtype=textquery
```

and get the following response:

```
{u'status': u'INVALID_REQUEST', u'html_attributions': [], u'results': []}
```

The same request works when I dont provide the *pagetoken* query param, but when I try to fetch the next page using this param, I run in to the above problem.

the pagination works fine with POSTMAN rest client, which leads me to believe im not encoding the url correctly.

```
while same_request:
    r = requests.get(url = URL, params = PARAMS)
    print r.request.url
    print r.request.headers
    print r.json()
    # extracting data in json format
    data = r.json()

    next_page_token = parse_results(data, False)
    print "recieved token>>>", next_page_token
    if next_page_token:
        same_request = True
        PARAMS['pagetoken'] = quote(next_page_token)
    else:
        same_request = False
```

Please help with the right way to encode, if that is infact the mistake im doing.

Answer (score 0):

Google requires a brief pause between consequent requests. a sleep for 2 seconds did the trick